# Stationarity condition for non-convex functions

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Suppose I have an objective function
$$
\min_{\bf x} f({\bf x}) + \lambda \|{\bf x}\|_1
$$
where $f({\bf x})$ is a differentiable non-convex function. I am trying to derive an upper bound for $\lambda$ similar to the procedure used in the lasso (as given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283976/choosing-lambda-for-multi-reponse-lasso-in-glmnet/348850)). Is it correct to state that

$$
{\bf 0}  \in f'({\bf x}) + \lambda \partial\|{\bf x}\|_1
$$
which leads
$$
\lambda > max(|f'({\bf 0})|) 
$$
for ${\bf x} = {\bf 0}$ to be a stationary solution.